Parsing bitwise data big-endian way using Python struct module
I have a hex string (put together from a hex dump file) which needs to be parsed in big-endian order to read individual bits.
Here are some examples of message structure with the expected value for each message from the hex string dd8d9880.



messages
size in bits
Start Byte
Start bits
Expected value




message1
8
0
0
221


message2
4
1
0
13


message3
4
1
4
8


message4
1
2
0
0


message5
1
2
1
0


message6
1
2
2
0


message7
3
2
3
3



How do I decode such hex strings to get those values. I am using python struct module but finding it difficult to understand the endianness and convert it accordingly.

Do you want to pass data between Python and C or what is reason for C tag?

Looks like a job for ctypes. It supports big endian structures and bit fields: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structure-union-alignment-and-byte-order

The "start bits" values are counting from the little end of each byte, so what makes this data "big endian"?

@IanAbbott Can you please explain what does it lean that start bits are counting from little end of each byte?

There are two ways to number the bits in a byte. In "LSb 0" bit numbering, bit 0 is the least significant bit of the byte value and bit 7 is the most significant bit of the byte value (assuming 8-bit bytes). In "MSb 0" bit numbering, bit 0 is the most significant bit of the byte value and bit 7 is the least significant bit of the byte value. For multi-byte values, in order for bit numbering to be consecutive across byte boundaries, it is conventional to use MSb 0 bit numbering for big-endian fields and LSb 0 bit numbering for little-endian fields.

However in hexadecimal notation, strings of bytes are written two hex digits per byte where the most significant hex digit is for the most signicant 4 bits of the byte value, and the least significant hex digit is for the least significant 4 bits of the byte value. Your hex string dd8d9880 is representing a string of 4 bytes dd 8d 98 80 rather than a single 32-bit value.

In interpreted as a single 32-bit, little endian value, the value would be 0x80988ddd and the starting bits of each message within the 32-bit value (in LSb 0 bit numbering) would be 0, 8, 12, 16, 17, 18, 19.

As mentioned in comments, the data is stored little-endian in bytes (least significant bit(LSB) is bit 0) to achieve the desired decoding.




byte1
byte2
byte3
byte4




bit position
76543210
7654 3210
76 543 2 1 0
76543210


bits
11011101 (0xDD)
1000 1101 (0x8D)
10 011 0 0 0 (0x98)
10000000 (0x80)



Below is a ctypes example:
import ctypes as ct

class Message(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('m1', ct.c_uint8),       # bits 0-7 of byte 1
        ('m2', ct.c_uint8, 4),    # bits 0-3 of byte 2
        ('m3', ct.c_uint8, 4),    # bits 4-7 of byte 2
        ('m4', ct.c_uint8, 1),    # bit 0 of byte 3
        ('m5', ct.c_uint8, 1),    # bit 1 of byte 3
        ('m6', ct.c_uint8, 1),    # bit 2 of byte 3
        ('m7', ct.c_uint8, 3),    # bits 3-5 of byte 3
        # Note that byte 3 bits 6-7 as are unused and this structure has a size of 3 bytes.
        # Uncomment below if you want the message to be 4 bytes and have access to remaining bits.
        # ('m8', ct.c_uint8, 2),  # bits 6-7 of byte 3
        # ('m9', ct.c_uint8),     # Added byte to make structure 4 bytes if you care.
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        # Makes a nice debug representation of Message when printed.
        return (
            f'Message(m1={self.m1}, m2={self.m2}, m3={self.m3}, m4={self.m4}, m5={self.m5}, m6={self.m6}, m7={self.m7}'
            # Uncomment below to print unused bits.
            # f', m8={self.m8}, m9={self.m9}'
            f')'
        )
# Create a message with the 4-byte hexadecimal string example.
m = Message.from_buffer_copy(bytes.fromhex('dd8d9880'))
print(m)

Output:
Message(m1=221, m2=13, m3=8, m4=0, m5=0, m6=0, m7=3)

Output with m8/m9 added for unused bits:
Message(m1=221, m2=13, m3=8, m4=0, m5=0, m6=0, m7=3, m8=2, m9=128)

